# Generic type parameter in .net(C#) whose value can by one of specified types?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Lets say I have classes `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `ClassC`. All of them inherit from `object` and non of them implements any interface.

Is it possible in C# to declare generic interface that will take generic argument `T` and that `T` may be either `ClassA` or `ClassB` or `ClassC` ?

So I would have something like

```
public interface MyInterface<T> where T: ClassA | ClassB | ClassC {
    ...
}
```

If it is possible what's the syntax?

---

*Note:* I know I could have those classes `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `ClassC` to implement some interface and than use it as constrain of `T` but before I create an interface that have no methods I want to know that there is no better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no better way.

You can only specify *one* base class or interface as that constraint.

But let me ask you this, why are you constraining to those 3 classes if they have nothing in common? Since you say you could constrain to an interface *with no methods*, what are you actually using from those classes?

With an interface constraint, the *only* thing you know is that the object used implements that interface.

Comment: know it looks rather strange but they actually have something in common but it is no method. Rather it is a fact that they are all POCO classes representing tables in database.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that, and *that's* what you have to tell it. Implement the interface. I know that "marker interfaces" are frowned upon in other places, FxCop among other places, but in this case, there really is no other way, unless you ditch the constraint altogether and add runtime checks instead (provided you can do that.)

Comment: @drasto: And what does that mean? Please, show an example, of how you want to use those classes inside your method

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible, because a type must meet **all** the constraints, not just one.
Anyway, if your interface wouldn't have a single method in it, it means that your classes have nothing in common. So how would you use them in your generic method anyway?
I think you are missing something important or didn't tell us the whole story.

Comment: For "non-classes" int | long would be a "good and valid" restriction.

Comment: @xanatos: I am not so sure. For the compiler, they are still two different types.

Comment: I mean "useful", not "valid". The fact that you can't restrict a generic class to "numbers" (entities with +, -, *, / defined) is a know limit of .NET

Comment: And I mean "(near) impossible" with the way generics are implemented in .NET. Because, what you really would need to do is define constraints on implemented operators, if you want to do that, i.e. "all class that implement + and -".

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth I certainly did not tell you the whole story... They have something in common but it is not a method... See my comment for @Lasse V. Karlsen's answer

Comment: There is the new() constraint, so there is already a constraint on a "special" method. It wouldn't probably require a step too much long.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer unless you wish to change programming language, but F# allows significantly more control than C# over specifying generics by using [Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx), up to and including 'Explicit Member Constraint' which is effectively static duck typing.

It also allows [Discriminated Unions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx) which would solve your problem for you in a different way.

All to say that the .net runtime does support this kind of thing, but there's no easy syntax for it in C#.

Comment: +1 good answer, good knowledge but no solution. I'm not going to learn J# syntax just because one interface and also having another project just because I want to have one interface there in J# seems to not to be good idea to me.

Comment: @drasto As noted it's not an answer to your specific situation: more a note that an answer has the potential to exist in the future! There are ways to implement things like Discriminated Unions in C# but as there's no syntax support they all involve a lot of unsatisfactory boiler plate.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Generic constraints are pretty limited at the moment.

They don't allow anything except type hierarchy, T being a reference type or T having a public parameterless ctor.